# Python 3 - OpenPyxl - How to write edited excel workbook to new excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Below is the python code to load a excel workbook and write some data on the sheet.

```
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl import Workbook

    new_excel = op.load_workbook('SpreadSheet.xlsx',read_only=False, keep_vba= True)

        spreadsheet = new_excel .get_sheet_by_name('Input Quote')

        spreadsheet['B30'] = 'VAU'
        spreadsheet['D30'] = 1000
        spreadsheet['F30'] = 5000
```

1) How can save this workbook in a separate excel(.xlsx) file?

2) If the
    excel has formulas , how can they be automatically triggered by 
    openpyxl API ?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

`import openpyxl
 workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('SpreadSheet.xlsx')
 workbook.save('NewWorkbook.xlsx')`

#### 2.

I am not sure if there is a better way to handle this, but when I need to check to see if there is a formula, I get the value of the cell (formulas are just strings) and do some data validation to check what the formula is. Then I replicate the functionality via Python, and output the appropriate data.

Comment: lets say you want to calculate the formula present in J13 cell ... how to replace it with the calculated value ? J13=A1+A2 ... should have 1000 if A1=A2=500 ..how do we calculate formula for the cell